# Maximum number of singular points on irreducible curve in $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, singularity

Let $C$ be a degree $d$ irreducible curve in $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$. Can we find maximum number of singular points in $C$?

For $d=2$, I find that there is no singular point on irreducible conic. (If there is a singular point, then consider any line $L$ passes through that singular point and any other point on $C$. If $L$ is not a component of $C$, by Bezout's theorem, we have $2=\sum I_{p}(C, L)\geq 1+2=3$, contradiction. (Here we use the fact that if $p$ is singular point of $C$, then $I_{p}(C, D)\geq 2$ for any curve passes $p$.)

For $d=3$, every irreducible cubic curve can have at most one singular point. If there are two singular points on $C$, consider a line connecting these two singular points. By Bezout's theorem again, $3=\sum I_{p}(C, L)\geq 2+2=4$, contradiction.

How can we generalize these argument? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The maximum number is $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$, the arithmetic genus of a degree $d$ curve. It can not be greater, since then the non-singular model of such a curve will have negative genus. One can achieve this, by taking the usual embedding of the projective line in $\mathbb{P}^d$ by degree $d$ complete linear system and taking a generic projection to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @Mohan I'm sorry, but I can't understand the last sentence. Can you briefly explain about complete linear system and generic projection?

Comment: If you take the map $\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^d$, given by all monomials $x^iy^{d-i}$, where $x,y$ are the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^1$, this gives an embedding of the line in $d$-space as a degree $d$ curve. Now, if you take a projection from a general linear subspace of dimension $d-3$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$, you can check that the image of the $\mathbb{P}^1$ has degree $d$ and exactly $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ ordinary double points.

Comment: @Mohan I'm not sure of your example; for exact, your example curve has degree $d$, but in general I have no idea how I can prove that it has exactly $\binom{d-1}{2}$ singular points.

Comment: @See-WooLee An example of irreducible plane curve of degree $d$ and exactly $\binom{d-1}{2}$ singular points is described in Fischer G. - _Plane Algebraic Curves_, chapter 3, section 9!

Comment: @Armandoj18eos You need to know that when you take such a generic projection as I described, the resulting curve has only ordinary double points and it is of course birational to the projective line which has genus zero. If $Y$ is a curve with only $r$ ordinary double points and arithmetic genus $G$, then the normalization has genus exactly $G-r$.